# Nodejs not found even its already installed

Tags: node.js

As you see I typed cd Program Files\nodejs and it was not found and went and check the environment variable to see if it's actually installed. I rebooted and still got the not found message on cmd. What am I missing? This is the first time I'm learning node.js.
[image: nodejs not found]

Comment: I already did that as shown on the screenshot.

Comment: I typed > node and got was > [....blank...]

Comment: That means node is in your path and working.  You don't need to worry about the fully qualified path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the full path (include the `C:\`)

```
cd c:\"Program Files"\nodejs
```